# Dynamic two dimensional array seems to allocate more memory

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to allocate a dynamic two dimensional array in C using the following code:

```
int **allocateMatrix(int rows, int columns) {

    int i = 0;
    int **p = NULL;

    p = (int**) calloc(rows, sizeof(int*));
    for(; i < rows; i++) {

        p[i] = (int*) calloc(columns, sizeof(int));
    }

    return p;
}
```

The code works but actually it's allocating double the memory it needs.

For example, if i pass the arguments `rows = 2` and `columns = 3` i get an array that's 2 rows by 8 columns.

Am i doing something wrong?

Thank you.

**Edit**:

The content of the matrix (which is loaded from a file) is:

```
-1 5 0
4 0 2
```

And this is what the memory looks like after the allocation and the assignment of the values:

[image: Memory]

Comment: How do you know it's allocating double the memory it needs? (Are you looking in a debugger?)

Comment: Actually it's more than the double. I know because when i try to assign values they're not contiguous in memory but they are shifted (i can see it from the watches in the debug window in netbeans).

Comment: Is it allocating memory for "int" in a way you don't expect? Try changing this to bit or long or float and see if the memory changes.

Comment: Are you sure your not confusing column/row order? You code looks correct.

Comment: @CharlieBurns No, rows and columns are correct, just checked it.

Comment: Are you taking into account the memory used by the row pointers? Your array will not be contiguos. See Jonathan's answer.

Comment: I believe the core of this issue is understanding what the debugger is actually doing.

Comment: Well you're all right, it was a my mistake. The program works perfectly. Thank you all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICT, your screenshot of the array having 20 elements is because.. you told Netbeans (with that `@20`) to display 20 elements starting at a memory location (`**(matrix)`). What happens when you change it to be '@3'?

However, based on this comment:

> Actually it's more than the double. I know because when i try to assign values they're not contiguous in memory but they are shifted (i can see it from the watches in the debug window in netbeans).

When you allocate memory, you're calling a library that figures out how to request from the operating system what space it may use and then of what space it's been given by the operating system what it hasn't used yet.

You're making assumptions about how the allocator works that may or may not be correct. It's possible for it to allocate space efficiently in a way you don't expect, especially due to virtual paging mechanisms. In short, contiguous calls to the allocator are not guarenteed to allocate contiguous memory, and rarely will.

If you want to use an array-of-pointers for a double array style structure and absolutely must have contiguous addresses in a more "expected" way, you can try this:

```
int **allocateMatrix(int rows, int columns) {

    int i = 0;
    int **p = NULL;
    int *d = NULL;


    p = (int**) calloc(rows, sizeof(int*));
    d = (int*) calloc(rows * columns, sizeof(int));

    for(; i < rows; i++) {
        p[i] = d + i * columns;
    }

    return p;
}
```

(code not tested)

Comment: When i change it to `@3` it just displays the first 3 elements. I thought that the elements in the columns where all contiguous and that's the mistake i made. Actually all the program works fine and results are correct. **Thank you for your precius help**. I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 3):

It is allocating the correct amount of memory, but it allocating more memory than a simple 2D array would use because what you've created is not a simple 2D array.

Assuming a 32-bit system (so `sizeof(int) == sizeof(int *)`, and `sizeof(int) == 4`), then:

- a simple 2D array needs 2 x 3 integers = 6 x 4 = 24 bytes
- a dynamic 2D array needs 2 pointers plus 2 x 3 integers = 8 x 4 = 32 bytes

That's before there's any accounting for overhead in the memory allocations.  So not twice, but more.

The advantages of what you're doing is you can write `p[i][j]` and get the right result.  If you simulated a simple 2D array, you'd have to do the subscript calculation yourself: `p[i*3+j]` or use `(*p)[i][j]`, depending on exactly how you defined the pointer `p`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. My mistake is that i didn't understand well how the debugger was working and your answer really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

that's not because it haves a bidimensional array size (rows*columns*sizeof(int*)) to store the pointers and a bidimensional array space to store the real values (rows*columns*sizeof(int))?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach (no extra memory needed for storing data, actually 1D continuous array in memory):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int (*allocateMatrix(int rows, int columns))[]{
    int (*p)[columns] = calloc(rows, columns * sizeof(int)),
        i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        p[i][j] = rows*i + j;
      }
    }
    return p;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int rows = 4, cols = 5,
     (*array)[cols] = allocateMatrix(rows,cols);

  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      printf("array[%d][%d] = %2d\n", i, j, array[i][j]);
    }
  }
  free(array);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
array[0][0] =  0
array[0][1] =  1
array[0][2] =  2
array[0][3] =  3
array[0][4] =  4
array[1][0] =  4
array[1][1] =  5
array[1][2] =  6
array[1][3] =  7
array[1][4] =  8
array[2][0] =  8
array[2][1] =  9
array[2][2] = 10
array[2][3] = 11
array[2][4] = 12
array[3][0] = 12
array[3][1] = 13
array[3][2] = 14
array[3][3] = 15
array[3][4] = 16
```